# WSO2 Enterprise integrator, Bearer Token

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-es

I'm using WSO2 6.5.0, i created proxy service which calls external REST API,

But I have to add Bearer Token to the Header,

*Please refer the below question :*

```
How to call rest service from wso2 proxy service using BEARER Token?
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ESB is working stateless, you have to set Bearer token from the client-side and send the request to the ESB.

Comment: How to do that, 
Can u provide some example
But i have to call external rest api which requires Authorization Bearer on HTTP header from WSO2 esb

Comment: Set this Bearer token in the request which you are calling the ESB proxy.

`curl -X POST -d @request.xml http://localhost:8280/services/yourProxy -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`

Comment: u do not get me? 
I need to call below service like that, Through my Proxy service, developed on WSO2,

curl -X POST -d @request.json http://ip:port/employee/1 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Comment: Then you can send the token in your request and set Authorization header inside the proxy using a **Header mediator**, before calling the service.

Comment: <header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
Like that??

Comment: i think it is working, Thank you 
By the chance, Do u know any sample rest api online which requires the authorization

Comment: you can check with Salesforce REST API. Dev account is free. Can we resolve this?